# -ms-perspective not working in internet explorer 10

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, internet-explorer-10, perspective

I'm trying to position divs with depth using the 'perspective:' and 'transform: translateZ' css properties. I have it working in Chrome, but not in IE10 or Firefox20.
You can see the test [here](http://www.girlguiding.org.uk/test/biggig/index.html), on the "Who's coming" menu page...

The containing div has the css class .scroller:

```
.scroller {  
    position: relative;  
    perspective: 150;  
    -webkit-perspective: 150;  
    -ms-perspective: 150;  
    -moz-perspective: 150;  
}
```

And, for the inner divs, translateZ is set using jQuery:

```
$(this).css('transform', 'translateZ(-' + ((1-$(this).css('opacity')) * 80) + 'px)');                           
$(this).css('-webkit-transform', 'translateZ(-' + ((1-$(this).css('opacity')) * 80) + 'px)');  
$(this).css('-ms-transform', 'translateZ(-' + ((1-$(this).css('opacity')) * 80) + 'px)');  
$(this).css('-moz-transform', 'translateZ(-' + ((1-$(this).css('opacity')) * 80) + 'px)');
```

But, it's not working in IE10 or Firefox20. Is there something I've missed?

Answer (score 2):

> "Do not use the Microsoft vendor prefix ("-ms-") before the perspective
>   property. It is supported unprefixed in Internet Explorer 10 and
>   later." - [MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772272%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I had it without the '-ms-' prefix originally and it wasn't working. Is there some other reason it was not working?

Comment: @moosefetcher Really? I'm guessing it's some other reason in that case if it wasn't working in ie10 as the MSDN seems pretty clear about it being possible :/ weird

Comment: @moosefetcher Check this link out of it being used in IE10, might be of a little use to you -  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/02/02/css3-3d-transforms-in-ie10.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link. Interesting - There's a comment at the bottom of that article that SEEMS to suggest 'perspective' doesn't work on Windows 7 (I'm running Windows 7). Anyone heard similar, or am I misinterpreting that comment?

Comment: @moosefetcher True, bear in mind though the comments were written over a year ago now, you'd have thought everything would be sorted out for IE10 on W7 by now..

Comment: So is there some other problem (that I'm not seeing) that someone's aware of? Any other reason the above code wouldn't work? (it didn't work WITHOUT the '-ms-' either).

Comment: @moosefetcher Post a jsFiddle? The only reason I can think would be your point of it being IE10 on Windows 7 instead of 8. Did you try that Article demo code on your computer to see if it works for you like in the example?

Comment: Hmm... not sure how to navigate jsfiddle, sorry. Can't get external images to load and there doesn't seem to be a discernable help (I click on external resources, but nothing happens). Maybe I'll post another question here without the '-ms-' issue muddying it. Unless someone else knows what the problem with the above code is (noting that 'perspective:' IS included AND that it didn't work in IE10 WITHOUT '-ms-' included). Cheers.

Comment: @moosefetcher What about posting it in jsBin? if not then I hope you find your solution soon anyway!

Comment: OK, I've got a jsFiddle going... http://jsfiddle.net/moosefetcher/rxCMr/20/ This has depth in Chrome, but not in IE10.

Comment: @moosefetcher Will take a look now